# How to access document data (e.g. error message) in alert message using "Per document monitor" with "Extraction Query" (OpenSearch Alerting)

Tags: opensearch

The `OpenSearch Alerting` [documentation](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/observing-your-data/alerting/monitors/) currently provides limited details specifically for the `Per document monitor` with `Extraction Query` use case. The available documentation only showcases one example for such a monitor and its corresponding alert message is quite basic:
`Monitor  just entered alert status. Please investigate the issue. Related Finding Ids: {{ctx.alerts.0.finding_ids}}, Related Document Ids: {{ctx.alerts.0.related_doc_ids}}`.

This setup only refers to findings and documents without including the actual data from the document or log. It would indeed be more beneficial if we could directly incorporate the document or log data into the alert.

The data might already be included somewhere within the context (`ctx`), but without comprehensive documentation or a detailed explanation of the `ctx` structure, I wan't able to find it. The `ctx.alerts` field, for instance, is referenced in the existing documentation only [once](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/observing-your-data/alerting/api/) and wan't described at all.

How can I configure a `Per document monitor` in OpenSearch to trigger actions on a `Per alert` basis while also incorporating specific log data within the alert message, similar to the functionality of a `Per query monitor` (via `ctx.results.0.hits.hits.0 ...`)?